# Attribute ref return null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get a reference to a DOM element in react is returning `null`, I have used selector methods and ref yet all returned null. The code those work well, as the dropdown is created, but the problem is:

while i click on the document or the button for the second time, i get an error message saying `this.containerElem is  null`.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isToggle: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isToggle: !this.state.isToggle,
    }, () => document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu.bind(this))
    );
  }

  closeMenu(ev) {
    if (!this.containerElem.contains(ev.target)) {
      this.setState({
        isToggle: !this.state.isToggle
      }, () => document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ClickBtn onHandleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
        {
          (this.state.isToggle) ? (
            <div className="menu"
              ref={(node) => {
                this.containerElem = node;
              }}
            >
              <button>Menu Item 1</button>
              <button>Menu Item 1</button>
              <button>Menu Item 1</button>
            </div>
          ) :
            (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function ClickBtn(props) {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={props.onHandleClick}>Click to Toggle</button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DropdownMenu />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You're only creating the ref when `this.state.toggle` is `true`. Also, `if(!this.containerElem.contains(ev.target)) {` probably isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Also you are creating a memory leak. `this.closeMenu.bind(this)` creates a new function. So your code always adds new global event listener, never  removes one, also you need to clean up when `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: thanks for your input, I think the problem is that within my closeMenu method, the click event listener  is not removed  as a result the function is call again, this time the ref element is not there.

Comment: You seems to have said it all, Thanks really have to look at some materials on these memory leak stuffs, any suggestions.

Comment: This article looks ok https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/